# Advanced forum: How to modify template of forum list page?

Tags: nodes

Here's the normal template for Advanced Forum:

[image]

I'd like to modify the template of advanced forum so that I can

1. Remove the elements in red
2. Rearrange the elements in blue
3. Edit the elements in green
4. Display the topic starter's profile2 picture

so that I can achieve the result below:

[image]

So far, I've tried editing advanced-forum.naked.topic-list.tpl.php but it doesn't change anything. I've managed to remove some of the content with Panels but I cannot modify what's left over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted (rearrange, add and remove fields, and set the display format for the time format) just by using views here : admin/structure/views/view/advanced_forum_topic_list

Answer (score 1):

When I had to do this I found there are lots of template files and it's not obvious what controls what. I ended up putting die() in each one to find out which template file was used for each view, and then a case of trial and error to make the changes I wanted.

When you have worked out which files need editing then you should copy them from:

```
/sites/all/modules/advanced_forum/styles/naked/advanced-forum.naked.TEMPLATE_NAME.tpl.php
```

to your theme at:

```
/sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/templates/advanced-forum.naked.TEMPLATE_NAME.tpl.php
```

Any files here will override the ones in the advanced forum themes folder.

Comment: Thanks :)  Now I've found the template file and I notice that they are printing things like $header and $rows. How do I modify the content of these variables? I ran global $rows; dsm($rows); with devel and nothing appears, but when I remove that line, it's clear that $rows contain information. running dsm($user) prints $user correctly so devel is working properly.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I've found what I need here admin/structure/views/view/advanced_forum_topic_list

Comment: Sounds like you've found it - it will be in another template file somewhere.

Comment: ah actually I didn't need to edit the template. I used views to acheive what I needed :)

Comment: Sounds like a good solution - those templates are tricky!

Answer (score 1):

Just to update the answer from @Felix Eve - if doing it in your own theme in Drupal 7 (which is recommended) then save the "naked" file here, ie with a hyphen and no "naked":

```
/sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/templates/advanced-forum-TEMPLATE_NAME.tpl.php
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This `naked` suffix is really weird.